# CGPoint array as a different struct

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Firebase and I am trying to database `[CGPoint]`s for a real time game. I tried changing the struct type to `[NSValue]` because at least it conforms to AnyObject (see code below), but now I get a runtime error. Any suggestions on how I can get my data into a struct it will accept without doing something crazy?

**Code**

```
func convert(points : [CGPoint]) -> [NSValue] {

    var tup = [NSValue]()

    for x in points {
        tup.append(NSValue(CGPoint: x))
    }

    return tup
}

func updateMap() {
    var userMap = [String:[AnyObject]]()

    userMap["forbiden"] = convert(forbiden)
    userMap["roadMap"] = convert(roadMap)
    userMap["settlementMap"] = convert(settlementMap)
    userMap["upgradeMap"] = convert(upgradeMap)

    self.ref.child(altUser+"/"+groupName+"/"+username).setValue(userMap)
}
```

**Run time error**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData',
>   reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type NSConcreteValue at
>   settlementMap.0. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString,
>   NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

Answer (score 1):

Not a particularly neat solution, but you *could* store your `CGPoint`'s as 2-element arrays (an array mimicing a 2-tuple) of `NSNumber` elements, in which case `.first` and `.last` would be used to access corresponding `x` and `y` coordinate, respectively, in the "fake tuple" 2-element array. E.g.

```
func convert(points : [CGPoint]) -> [[NSNumber]] {

    var fakeTuples = [[NSNumber]]()

    for point in points {
        fakeTuples.append([NSNumber(double: point.x.native),
                      NSNumber(double: point.y.native)])
    }

    return fakeTuples
}
```

Or, in a more compact form

```
func convert(points : [CGPoint]) -> [[NSNumber]] {
    return points.map {
        [NSNumber(double: $0.x.native),
        NSNumber(double: $0.y.native)]
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one convert `[[NSNumber]]` back to a `CGPath`?